# Как отображать различное количество абзацев?

Tags: jquery

Необходимо, используя библиотеку jquery (компонент tracker), позволить пользователю отображать различное количество абзацев текста на странице, в зависимости от положения «ползунка».

Comment: Кстати, кинь линк на описание твоего "tracker"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ох... 
Счяс.

Я тут маленький плагин накатал на скорую руку.... может пригодится.
Во всяком случае- без глюков крутит более 10.000.000 элементов :)

```
(function(jQuery){
    jQuery.fn.createVirtualTable = function(options){
        var opt = jQuery.extend({
            remark: 4,
            objects: null,
            count: 10,
            search: 0,
            objname: null,
            width: "485px"
        },options);

        var tmp = {
            mid: null,
            objects: null
        }

        var create = function(data , pos, id) {
            var str = "";
            var count = opt.count;
            if (!data)
                data = opt.objects;
            if (!pos)
                pos = 0;    
            if (!id)
                id="";
            for (var i = pos; data.length > i; i++) {
                if (count && i >= (count + pos))
                    break;
                var elem = data[i];
                if(!elem)
                    continue;
                if (!id && elem.init)
                    var tmpid = elem.init + "&";
                else
                    var tmpid = id + i + "&";
                str += "<" + elem.type;
                if (elem.attr) {
                    for (key in elem.attr) {
                        if ( elem.attr[key] )
                            str += " " + key + "='" + elem.attr[key] + "'";
                    }
                }
                if ( elem.type == "input" ) {
                    str += " init='" + tmpid + "' /> ";
                    continue;
                }
                str += " init='" + tmpid + "' > ";
                if(elem.html)
                    str += elem.html;
                if (elem.child)
                    str += create(elem.child, '',tmpid);
                str += " </" + elem.type + ">";
            }
            return str;
        }
        var srchTpl = function (text, template) {
            var pattern = template.toLowerCase();
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\./g, "\\.");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\?/g, ".");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\*/g, ".*");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\^/g, "\\^");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\$/g, "\\$");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\+/g, "\\+");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\(/g, "\\(");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\)/g, "\\)");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\[/g, "\\[");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\]/g, "\\]");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\{/g, "\\{");
            pattern = pattern.replace(/\}/g, "\\}");
            return text.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp('^' + pattern + '$'));
        }

        var find = function (search, e) {
            tmp.objects = null;
            var mid = e[0].id;
            if(!search) {
                build('',jQuery("#" + mid),opt.objects);
                return;
            }
            if(search.indexOf("*") < 0 && search.indexOf("?") < 0)
                var search = "*" + search + "*";
                var search = search;            
            var arr = [];
            var c = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < opt.objects.length ; i++) {
                var str = opt.objects[i].index.toLowerCase();
                var test = srchTpl(str ,search);
                if (test != null) {
                    arr[c] = opt.objects[i];
                    c++;
                }   
            }   
            if(arr.length  == 0 )
                tmp.objects = ".";
            else    
                tmp.objects = arr;

            build('',jQuery("#" + mid),  tmp.objects);
        }

        var build = function (y,el,data) {

            var wh = opt.objects.length;            
            if (!y)
                var y = jQuery("#" + el[0].id + "-visible").scrollTop();
            if (y > 2) {
                var y = Math.round(y / opt.remark);
            }   
            if (y >= ((wh - opt.count))) {
                var y = wh  - opt.count;
                if(y < 1) var y = 0;
            }

            el.css({top : (y * opt.remark)});
                if(!data) 
                    el.html(create(null, y));
                else if (data == ".")
                    el.html(" ");
                else
                    set_html(el[0].id,data,y);

        }
        var reinit = function (e) {
            var el = jQuery(e);
            var n = el.attr("init").split("&");
            var obj = opt.objects;
            var tmp = "";
            var tmp2 = "";
            for (var i=0; i < n.length; i++ ) {
                if(!n)
                    continue;
                if(!n[i])   
                    break;                  
                if (i == 0) {
                    obj = obj[n[i]];
                    tmp += "[" + n[i] + "]";
                    tmp2 += tmp;
                } else {
                    obj = obj.child[n[i]];
                    tmp += ".child[" + n[i] + "]";
                    if((n.length -1) > i)
                        tmp2 += ".child";
                }
            }
            if (e.type == "checkbox") {
                if(e.checked)
                    eval("opt.objects" + tmp + ".attr.checked = 1");
                else    
                    eval("opt.objects" + tmp + ".attr.checked = 0");
            }
            if (e.type == "text")
                eval("opt.objects" + tmp + ".attr.value = '"+e.value + "'");
            if (e.type == "radio") {
                if (e.checked) {
                    var broth = obj.broth;
                    var broth = broth.split(",");
                    eval("opt.objects" + tmp + ".attr.checked = 1");
                    for (var i = 0 ; broth.length > i; i++)
                        eval("opt.objects" + tmp2 + "[" + broth[i] + "].attr.checked = ''");
                }

            }
            if(opt.objects.length)
                eval(opt.objname + "= opt.objects;");
        }
        var set_html = function (eid,data, y) {
            var wh = opt.objects.length;
            var html = null;
            if (tmp.objects != null)
                var wh = tmp.objects.length;

            if (data && data != undefined) 
            {
                jQuery("#" + eid + "-unvisible").css({ height: Math.round(data.length * opt.remark) });

                if((y - opt.count) < opt.count)
                    var html = create(data, y);
                else
                    var html = create(data, (y - opt.count));

                if(html)
                    jQuery("#" + eid).html(html);
                else {
                    jQuery("#" + eid).html( " " ).css({ top: 0 });
                    build(null, jQuery("#" + eid), data);
                    if (jQuery.browser.opera)
                        jQuery("#" + eid + "-visible").scrollTop(jQuery("#" + eid).css("top"));
                    return;
                }

            }
            else
                jQuery("#" + eid).html(create(opt.objects));

            jQuery("#" + eid).css({
                position : "relative" 
            });

            jQuery("#" + eid + "-visible").css({
                position : "relative",             
                height: jQuery("#" + eid).height(),
                "overflow" : "auto"     
                });

            if(!data) {
                var uh = Math.round(jQuery("#" + eid + "-visible").height());
                if(wh> opt.count)
                    var uh = wh * opt.remark;
                jQuery("#" + eid + "-unvisible").css({
                        position : "relative",
                        height: uh
                        });

            }

        }

        return this.each(function() {
            if (opt.objname == null || opt.objects == null)
                return; 
            jQuery(this).wrap("<div id='" + this.id + "-visible' style='margin-top: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #B4B4B4; owerflov-y: true';>");
            jQuery(this).wrap("<div id='" + this.id + "-unvisible'>");
            if(opt.search) {
                var main_id = this.id;
                jQuery("#" + this.id + "-visible").before("<div id='" + this.id+ "-search' style='margin-top: \"10px\"; border-top:\" 1px solid #B4B4B4\"' >" +
                    opt.search + ": <input type='text' id='" +this.id + "-search-input' style='margin-top: 10px;' value='' /></div>"
                    );
                jQuery("#" + this.id + "-search-input").keyup(function () {
                    find(this.value, jQuery("#" + main_id));
                }); 
            }

            set_html(this.id);

            jQuery("#" + this.id + "-visible").scroll(function() {

                if (tmp.objects) {

                    build(jQuery(this).scrollTop(),jQuery(this).children().children(),tmp.objects);
                } else {

                    build(jQuery(this).scrollTop(),jQuery(this).children().children());
                }   
            });
            var wdth = jQuery("#" + this.id).width();
            jQuery("#" + this.id + "-visible").css({width: wdth + 'px'});
            jQuery(this).click(function(event) {
                if(jQuery(event.target)[0].type == "text"){
                    jQuery(jQuery(event.target)[0]).keyup(function () {
                        reinit(jQuery(event.target)[0]);
                    });
                } else if (jQuery(event.target)[0].type == "checkbox" || jQuery(event.target)[0].type == "radio")
                    reinit(jQuery(event.target)[0]);
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery)
```

И вотрая функция (для забора изменений):

```
var jQueryVirtual = {
    constructor: null,
    get_params: function (option, dom , attr) {
        if (!dom)
            return false;
        var str = "";
        var txt = "";
        for (var i = 0; dom.length > i; i++) {
            var elem = dom[i];
            if ( elem.type.toLowerCase() == "input" ) {
                if (elem.attr) {
                    for (var key in elem.attr) {
                        if ( key == "val" || key == "value" && elem.attr[key] != "") {
                            if (option && elem.attr.type == option) {
                                if (option == "radio"|| option == "checkbox" && elem.attr.checked) {
                                    if(attr && !elem.attr[attr]) 
                                        continue;
                                    str +=  "," + elem.attr.val;

                                }
                            }
                            if (elem.attr.type == "text") {
                                if (elem.attr.value != undefined ) {
                                    str += "_" + elem.attr.value;
                                }   
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
            if (elem.child && attr) {
                str += this.get_params(option ,elem.child, attr);
            }   
            else if (elem.child && !attr) {
                str += this.get_params(option ,elem.child, null);
            }   
        }
        return str;
    }                
};
```

Пример использования:

Создаем массив объектов из элементов, которые предположительно будут выведены на страницу:

```
html_arr[j] = { type:"tr", index: name, attr: 
        { val: "value", is_unit: "0" ,style: "width: 10px; height: 20px" }, 
        child: [{type: "td", attr: { colspan: 1,style: "margin-right: 20px;"},
            child:[{ type: "input", attr: 
                {  id: "myid"+j, type:"checkbox", val:id , checked: "1"}
         }]
     }]
};
```

И подключаем плагин:

```
jQuery("#id-element").createVirtualTable({
    objects:  html_arr,    //Сам массив
    objname: ' html_arr', //Название массива
    search: "Поиск", //Этот параметр нужен если нужно окошко поиска
    remark: 24 //Это лучше не менять. Ремарка высоты анвизибл дива (для регулятора скрола)
});
```

Сорри за много текста :))

P.S. Плагин сырой но рабочий :))
Если у кого-то есть замечания - буду рад их выслушать :)